# Need help in Sql query joining operation

Tags: sql

I have below test table with data:

```
Create table test
(
   col1 int,
   col2 int
)
```

Sample data:

```
col1    col2
-------------
1       4
1       5
2       4
3       5
3       4
```

Now I want all the col1 which have col2 value 4 and 5
o/p 1,3 since it contain 4 as well as 5 col2 value

Comment: you need `col1 ,col2` if `col2` got value 4 ? please explain bit confusing. the output you want is very misleading and unclear.

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far, and what results that gave you?

Comment: please provide sample result set ...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE col1 IN 
(
 SELECT col1 
 FROM TestTable 
 WHERE col2 = 4 
)
AND col2 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need col1 value, you can do

of course, the value in the having clause (2 in this case) depends on the numbers of elements in the IN clause (so if you have 3, 4, 5, you'll need to put 3 in the having clause)

```
select col1 from test t1
where col2 in (4, 5)--take only results with 4 and 5 in col2
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 2 --be sure there's at least a 4 and a 5
```